# Is there anywhere to get a haircut at Miami International Airport?

Tags: airports, layovers, hygiene, services, miami

Tomorrow I'll have a 2-hour layover in Miami International Airport (MIA) on my way to a job interview.  Is there anywhere within the airport that I can get a haircut?  I don't see any such options [here](http://www.miami-airport.com/services_and_amenities.asp), so I'm guessing the answer is no, but hoping that the listing there is incomplete.

Comment: I guess it was at one point: http://www.miami-area-guide.com/miami_International_Airport.html

Comment: Definitely used to be: http://199.119.0.60/html/services_at_mia.html

Comment: There are personal services companies that will arrange a barber or hairdresser for you.  You can consider that option if you find nothing else available.

Comment: Or you can go for the [world famous André Agassi Mach 3 look](http://m.youtube.com/results?q=andre%20agassi%20gillette&sm=3). Get a beard razor and shave it all off.

Comment: Well, my flight into Miami ended up being delayed, and immigration was backed up worse than I've ever seen, so I ended up arriving at my departing gate just minutes before they closed the door.  So I didn't have any time to look for (or really even care) about hair cuts there. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of July 2015 there is currently not a location to get a haircut at Miami airport

[This link](http://www.shopmiamiairport.com) lists all of the retail, food, and services at Miami airport has an information page on [what to do during a layover](http://www.miami-airport.com/what_to_do_during_layovers.asp) including information on art exhibitions at the airport.